# I want to delete a value of a index on a arrayand print it in a String, Java

Tags: java, recursion

I want to delete a value of an array, like this:

```
String[] vector = {Jhon, Snow, You, Dont, Know, Nothing};
```

I want to delete the value Jhon and print something like:

```
Snow, You, Dont, Know, Nothing, null.
```

I have to use a recursive method.  I have this so far:

```
public static String DeleteValue(
    String[] stringVector, int index, String list) {

    if (index == 0) {
        stringVector[index] = null;
        list += stringVector[index] + ""; }
    if(index < stringVector.length-1){
        stringVector[index] = stringVector[index+1];
        return DeleteValue(stringVector, index,list); }
    else{
        return DeleteValue(stringVector,index++,list);
    }
}
```

Comment: for now, i can delete the value of the first index, but can't move the others values to the left, i get some overstack and other times don't return the value at all

Comment: can you add your code snippet ?

Comment: So basically you loop through `index` to `arr.length-2` copying `index`+1 to it, then replace the last element with null? Wonder how that is done.

Comment: i have this code:
 public static String DeleteValue(String[] stringVector, int index, String list) {

if (index == 0) {
stringVector[index] = null;
list += stringVector[index] + "";
}

if(index < stringVector.length-1){
stringVector[index] = stringVector[index+1];
return DeleteValue(stringVector, index,list);
}   else{
return DeleteValue(stringVector,index++,list);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void remove(String[] list, String s, int next, int index) {
    if (index >= list.length) {
        while (next < list.length)
            list[next++] = null;
    } else {
        if (!s.equals(list[index]))
            list[next++] = list[index];
        remove(list, s, next, index + 1);
    }
}
```

And

```
String[] vector = {"Jhon", "Snow", "You", "Dont", "Know", "Nothing"};
remove(vector, "Jhon", 0, 0);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vector));
```

result:

```
[Snow, You, Dont, Know, Nothing, null]
```

Or if you don't like `while`

```
static void remove(String[] list, String s, int next, int index) {
    if (index >= list.length) {
        if (next < list.length) {
            list[next++] = null;
            remove(list, s, next, index);
        }
    } else {
        if (!s.equals(list[index]))
            list[next++] = list[index];
        remove(list, s, next, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm idk, but in class the prof say to us that in recursive method we can't use loops like while, for and stuff, i try your code and it works, and i thanks a lot your help, but i need a code with recursive method ;-;

Comment: @JavaNovice Updated.

Comment: OMG ty so muchhh >o< you help me a lot, i notice in what i was wrong, ty ty ty